# Error message of "framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement" when i run my project

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I have these Pods in my project

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'ActiveLabel'
```

when I run the app on Xcode I get a error message "framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement" most of the time,
sometimes the app runs without a problem but for the most part it fails with this message appearing

Does anyone know why this is happening and a fix for this please

Comment: Your podfile is out of date. See the [installing firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods) *You no longer need to add the iOS pod Firebase/Core.* and the other pods may be out of date as well. First thing to try is to update the podfile and do a `pod update` or `pod install` from the project folder, ensuring your project is closed. The error is tied back to FirebaseAnalytics fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Close Xcode and open your Derived Data Folder and clear it. Reopen the project clean it (cmd+shift+k) and run again.

> Don't for get to set Build Active Architecture Only to No in build
>   setting.